# Variables in rails with compass not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, asset-pipeline, compass-sass, sass

I am playing around with The Rails Pipeline and the "Compass" GEM.

I wanna style my links and tried with this:

```
// File /assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

$grey: "#97A5A3";

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

    &:hover {
        color:$grey;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    &:visited {
        color: $grey;
    }
    &:active {
        color: $grey;
    }
    &:visited {
        color: $grey;
    }
}
```

But it wont work...

When I turn the variables into a HEX Code ("#123456") or an white ("white") it works. 
They stay in the "standard" blue, violett schema.

How should I use variables instead if not so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `"` from `"#97A5A3"`.

```
$grey: #97A5A3;
```

On this [site](http://sass-lang.com/try.html) you can check the CSS generated by your Sass code, which facilitate to find any error.

I hope it solves your problem....

Comment: many thanks

In the meanwhile I had done it with  --->   #{$color} 
But yours beats it all.. 

many thanxx

(thanks for the nice cool link)